# Authentication failed when connect other git in Azure Pipelines with PAT

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-repos

I'm trying to create a connection with Azure Pipelines and my Private Git, as image bellow:

[image]

I created a new PAT with full access and put it inside the Password / Token field.

[image]

When I run the command on my local machine, I am able to clone normally using the following commands.

```
$MyPat = 'MYPAT'
$B64Pat = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes(":$MyPat"))
git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Basic $B64Pat" clone http://tfs.MYURL:8081/tfs/Desenvolvimento/Projetos/_git/MyProject
```

But when I try to run my pipeline, I get the following error:

[image]

Any tips for authenticating pipelines with a private git repository? I've tried to put PAT in base64 in the Password / Token field, but without success too...

Comment: I can see this issue when using Microsoft-hosted agents to access to TFS private repo because this TFS is behind proxy/firewall. Is your TFS the same settings, or can access to this private repo from public network not your local network?

Comment: Hi, that’s it, I’m trying to connect Azure Pipelines from Azure DevOps Services to a private Azure Repos.

Yes, I can connect to this repository from a public network, I have already done some tests using the command line below:

git -c http.extraHeader="Authorization: Basic $B64Pat" clone https://tfs.MYURL:8081/tfs/Desenvolvimento/Projetos/_git/MyProject

If I use this command line above in an environment outside the network, I can clone the repository, however, when I try to connect the pipelines, I get the error according to the message above.

Comment: You could follow this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops to add certain IP addresses and domain URLs to the allowlist. Adding them to the allowlist helps to ensure that you have the best experiences with Azure DevOps.

Comment: I think the problem is not IP blocking, because if I do the git clone inside a powershell task I can, normally. The problem is in the way that the Task Checkout Repository is connecting to the repository. If you notice on the command line above, I am passing the extraHeader parameter with PAT in Base64, however in connection with Git I cannot use this connection.